# Should I be concerned about my 2.5-year-old daughter nearly always picking the colour black?

Tags: toddler, behavior

She draws nearly always with a black crayon or pen or uses very dark colours. When she has to pick a pipe for drinking, it is the same - the pipe is always black or dark, though we have nearly a rainbow of colours to choose from. When bathing, she nearly always plays with a black duck. Actually, I have the feeling, that the only reason, why she isn't always wearing black dresses, is because we haven't bought her any in this colour yet.

Is this something, that I should look for or should I rather take it as a short time behaviour, that is going to pass sooner or later?

Comment: Do you mean to ask if you should be worried about whether or not your daughter has a visual impairment?

Comment: No. I mean to ask, if this is something normal, that she paints everything in black or uses mostly black toys.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Does she know her colors yet? I would be very surprised if she could. I also would be very surprised if she cared.

Parents tend to worry about children's color preferences. Boys who like pink. Girls who like black. Heaven help the mother of a child who insists on only wearing white - unless dad does the laundry. Then, heaven help *him*

Colors are a much bigger deal for parents than kids. The odds aren't that your daughter is colorblind. The odds are very far from the chance that your daughter will be a goth. Let the sweet little child play without any cares on your part.

She may just find the high contrast between black and white attractive (I assume she's coloring on white paper? If you gave her black paper, she might pick up a white pastel to draw on it. Who knows?

If you're worried, she should have a doctor visit coming up. Mention it to the doctor. He might have her tested for her vision. They test for color blindness later.

Meanwhile, it's cool that she has such well developed preferences. Celebrate her individuality! Black backgrounds are wonderful for pops of color at a party.

[Why Johnny Can't Name His Colors](http://www.scientificamerican.com/article/why-johnny-name-colors/) 
[How to teach your child colors](http://www.kevinmd.com/blog/2013/11/teach-child-colors.html)

Comment: Thanks for a great answer. "Heaven help the mother..." part just made my day! :>

Comment: +1 for the high contrast suggestion. I prefer bold, dark colors over pastels myself :)

Comment: "Does she know her colors yet? I would be very surprised if she could" Is it uncommon for a 2 and half year old to know their colours?

Comment: @Tom.Bowen89 - Yes. See the first link. :)

Comment: @anongoodnurse that's crazy to me. Our two year old has been great at colours for a while now. Can even distinguish pink and red...etc. I assumed this was normal.

Comment: @Tom.Bowen89 - You're arguing with a scientific study, not me. Find a better article which is reliable, and I'll remove the statement! :D

Comment: @Tom.Bowen89 - This reminds me of something amazing. I was in B&BW, and there was a little girl in front of me reading the labels, and I mean *little*. I thought she was mimicking someone. Being very curious, I asked her to read a different label. "Cucumber and Spring Lily," she sounds out. I pointed to another. "Ocean Citrus," she says slowly. She was clearly reading. I turned to her mother and asked her how old her daughter was. She was two and a half, and her mother never taught her to read; she picked it up on her own! Some kids just amaze.

Comment: In my experience, kids change their color preference a lot until they are like 5. Our son went though yellow, black, blue, orange. Now that I'm old, I'm not sure I even have a favorite anymore.